# In Angular2, How do I send from JSON from service/component to my HTML component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular2 and spent a lot of time trying to fix a simple thing. 
As you can see, I only want to access the Local Storage (bottom function, `ui()`)and send the contents to the `View, Register.components.html.` I tried various blog but I failed every-time.

So I can't really post an error, but how do I just access the local storage and display the contents to my view? Also `ui()` isn't being called. How do I call it?

`Register.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidateService} from '../../services/validate.service';
import {AlarmService} from '../../services/alarm.service';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

   hours: String;
   id: String;

  constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService, 
    private FlashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private Router: Router,
    private AlarmService: AlarmService
    ){ 
    }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onRegisterSubmit(){
    var user = {
        hours: (new Date(this.hours.replace('T', ' ').replace('-', '/'))).valueOf(),
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      flag: 0
    }    

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.FlashMessage.show('Your alarm has been added.', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000});
      }, 10);  

     var storage = localStorage.getItem('users');
     var final = [];
      if (storage == null || typeof(storage) == undefined )
      {  final.push(user);

       localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(final));
       let time = new Date().getTime()

       this.AlarmService.setUpAlarms(time);

      }else{
       var get =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
       var size = Object.keys(get).length;

       for(var i =0; i< get.length; i++){
           final.push(get[i]);
       }
       final.push(user);
       localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(final));        
       let time = new Date().getTime()

       this.AlarmService.setUpAlarms(time);
      }        
   } 

  ui(){

      var storage = localStorage.getItem('users');

      if (storage == null || typeof(storage) == undefined ){
         var HERO = localStorage.getItem('users');

       }
       console.log(HERO);
    const HEROES =  HERO
  }
}
```

This is my HTML view

```
<form (submit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
<div class = "container">
  <div class="overlay">

  <div id="alarm-dialog">
HEKK
    <h2>Set alarm at</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="hours">
      <input type="datetime-local"  pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hours" name="hours"  value="0" min="0"  required/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <a class="close"></a>
  </div>

</div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Set Alarm">
</div>
</form>

 <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
                <td>{{hero.hours}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `ui()` called when the component loads, you can do it in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ui();
}
```

Also, declare `heroes` as a property on your component so it can be bound to the view:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes: any[]; // Maybe add a type instead of "any"

   // etc
}
```

And fix up your `ui` method a bit:

```
ui() {
    this.heroes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Frank. However, What type do I give? It is returned as an array. So what type do I add? If I add String, it prints only Object, object.

Comment: If `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))` returns an array (confirm this!), you should be OK with `heroes: any[]`. If you have defined a type already, you could do `heroes: YourType[]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me. I have one more question, can you please tell me how do I make the function in a service recursive?

Comment: You're welcome. A recursive service function seems unrelated to this question, so you may want to ask a new one.